# Javascript: how to check/delete a css style tag in the head of the document

Tags: javascript, css

I inject a style via javascript in the head of a document in this way:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(style);
style.innerHTML = "a, .left-hand { cursor:wait; }";
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to check if this style is in the document (considering that there others) and how to delete it.

Thanks

Comment: There may be a better way to achieve what you want (e.g. by setting a body class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep the reference around, in this case the `style` variable.

To check if it's still in the DOM, check if it has a parent using `parentNode`. If it does, it's still in the DOM. If it does not (`null`), it's not in the DOM.

To remove it:

```
if(style.parentNode){                     //check if it has a parent
    style.parentNode.removeChild(style);  //if it does, this is how to remove it
}
```

Even after this, as long as something still references the style tag, in this case the `style` variable, you can still reappend it to the DOM. `removeChild` only removes the element from the DOM, and it does not clear references.